# Can't Align Text to the Center in a Rounded Rectangular Button in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, alignment

I am a beginner in Photoshop. I can't align the text to the center in a rounded rectangular button. I have tried using "align vertical center" and "align horizontal center" options. But they do not work. Please, see the screenshot.[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the align tool Photoshop provides on this menu:

[image]

You need to select both layers you want to align before clicking. You can also check the alignment on View > Rulers, use the guides by clicking on the ruler and dragging the line until you find the middle of your shape. Like this:
[image]

Sometimes the font you're using may have line height differences so the alignment doesn't look right, in that case you need to manually align the text.